# I'm trying to access an AWS API Gateway inside of a VPC, but keep getting timeout errors

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, zappa

I have an AWS API gateway that I created with zappa and an ECR docker image. I assigned the lambda function to a VPC but can no longer access the API.

I created an internet gateway and have the route table routing 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0 to it.

I have all traffic allowed on all ports on the security group as well.

However, whenever I try to access any endpoints I get a timeout error. If I take the lambda function out of the VPC I am able to access all the endpoints.

Comment: Any findings on this issue?

Answer (score -2):

You cannot access API gateway from lambda directly, if your lambda inside VPC. In this case you have to use VPC endpoint.

> You can use Lambda functions to proxy HTTP requests from API Gateway to an HTTP endpoint within a VPC without Internet access. This allows you to keep your EC2 instances and applications completely isolated from the internet while still exposing them via API Gateway. By using API Gateway to front your existing endpoints, you can configure authentication and authorization rules as well as throttling rules to limit the traffic that your backend receives.

Reference: [https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-with-vpc-endpoints-via-aws-lambda/#:~:text=Conclusion,exposing%20them%20via%20API%20Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-with-vpc-endpoints-via-aws-lambda/#:%7E:text=Conclusion,exposing%20them%20via%20API%20Gateway)

Comment: This link does not address the OP's question. OP does not want to route requests from API Gateway to a private VPC, but rather they want to access an API Gateway resource (I'm assuming via HTTP) FROM a Lambda living inside a private VPC that has a configured IG for public access. Our group is facing the same timeout issue.